# insert a python list's content into an SQL column

Tags: python, mysql, list

I have been facing some problems when it comes to SQL requests written in Python.

I have to put a list's content in a table and I can't seem to be able to do it. 
Let's say the list is A=[1,2,3,...,n]

I use the following code:

```
for i in range(len(A)):
    cur.execute("insert into table1 (list) values('"+str(A[i])+"')")
```

where table1 is my table and list is a column there. The table is empty and all modules for MYSQL have been imported. I am connected to the database. 
The bummer is that I've used this kind of request so many times these past days and it worked so I am really frustrated over it. All I get is an empty table.

Can anyone see the error in this?

Comment: It would be (is always ....) better to use parameters for the values: `cur.execute("insert into table1 (list) values(?)", (str(A[i]),))` But if the values in A are just integers, that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: (Also to be more pythonic, `for i in range(len(A): ... A[i] ...` could be `for a in A: ... a ...`)

Comment: Are you committing the transaction? Are you closing the connection?

Comment: Can you tell what exactly the *error* was??